# Can I use a Center Lock hub and disc brake rotor in place of an ISO hub?

Tags: brakes, rotor, disc-brake

I currently have a regular ISO disc brake hub and rotor on my front wheel. I'd like to replace it with a Shimano generator hub, but all Shimano hubs use Center Lock rotors instead of ISO. The Center Lock to ISO adapters seem really hokey, so I was thinking I could just get a new Center Lock rotor of the same size.

I don't know how to tell if the left-to-right alignment of the rotors is the same between the two mounting standards. Will this work without any additional adapters or modifications?

Comment: Shimano 6 bolt dynamo's do exist but may be harder to come by the 2014 nexus model is the DH-3D32. It just may make sense to keep standards aligned for the front and back wheel in case you ever have to replace callipers. If you are using Shimano brakes it doesn't matter as they don't ship with rotors but Avids generally ship with a 6 bolt rotor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the original question, but I'm curious because I have a Shimano dynamo hub and disc brakes (Avid BB7). I currently have an adapter on hub, with the rotor bolted to it. So, if I replace the Avid rotor with a Shimano rotor, I can get rid of the adapter and everything will work — is that what this is about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this should work just fine. CenterLock and ISO six bolt wheels should be interchangeable w/o problems as long as they use the same rotor diameter.

Comment: Yep, another vote saying that this will work fine...

Comment: I have this setup on a recumbent. Avid brakes with one six-bolt and one centerlock rotor. Works just fine.

Comment: This isn't center-lock specific, but there is one possible issue. With certain rotors, particularly Shimano rotors with the huge black spider part (e.g. RT-76), there may be clearance issues with brakes that come close to the hub (e.g. the pad removal tab on Avid BB7s).

Comment: I was just about to add exactly the same comment about aluminum spiders on some rotors.

Comment: Set this up yesterday and it works great. For anyone else going down this route, make sure to get a rotor that includes a lockring, and have a lockring tool available.