# Using different style disc rotors with the same brake calipers

Tags: wheels, disc-brake, rotor

I currently have a set of TRP Hy/Rd brakes that came with 6-bolt style rotors.  I am interested in purchasing a different wheelset that uses Shimano's centerlock style hubs.  One wheelset would serve as my race wheelset, and the other would be for training, so ideally I would like to swap between the two with little trouble.

I am wondering if the current brakes I use would even accept centerlock rotors, and if so, is there an adjustment I would need to make that makes swapping between 6-bolt and centerlock a difficult process?

Comment: See the answers to this question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20381/can-i-use-a-center-lock-hub-and-disc-brake-rotor-in-place-of-an-iso-hub/20383#20383

Comment: Do you mean training on rollers or out on training rides?  If on rollers then brakes aren't required at all.

Comment: @Criggie: Outdoor training rides, to be more specific.  My race wheelset uses tubular tires, so they're not exactly ideal for long distance training outdoors.

Comment: When you get off rollers, you often use the rear brake, so you might want the brakes anyway (plus something may go wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've gotta try it out to some extent (e.g. at your LBS). But you'll likely be able to do it with some spacers, tweaking of the brakes and [some fidgeting](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/10/bikes-and-tech/how-to-convert-a-10-speed-29er-wheel-to-a-cross-disc-hoop-and-align-rotors_306588) and appropriate part selection. If you do it right, you should have minimal/no adjustment between swapping the wheelsets.

It depends on the brakes and rotors you have. In some cases, the rotor will fit fine or need a minor adjustment in pad placement, while in other cases you won't get the rotor to be able to align properly or the rotor will be too wide and maybe have suboptimal braking (e.g. excessive pad wear or reduced braking power). You may be buying a Centerlock->6 bolt rotor adapter depending on the rotors you're planning to run or some spacers or something to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the info.  I'll stop by the LBS and see if they have some centerlock hubs/rotors I can experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

as long as the rotors are the same size diameter ,absolutely no problem